# Issues Updating aws ec2 Instance

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Whenever I try to update my EC2 instance, I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                                                | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
817 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package aws-cfn-bootstrap.noarch 0:1.4-30.21.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package aws-cfn-bootstrap.noarch 0:1.4-31.22.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.53.1-16.85.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.53.1-16.86.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package db4.x86_64 0:4.7.25-18.11.amzn1 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-libs-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-build-libs-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: ruby20-libs-2.0.0.648-1.31.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: iproute-4.4.0-3.23.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: python27-libs-2.7.15-1.124.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: pam-1.1.8-12.33.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: httpd24-tools-2.4.37-1.83.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: pam_ccreds-10-4.9.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: httpd24-2.4.37-1.83.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-python27-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: cyrus-sasl-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: apr-util-1.5.4-6.18.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: sendmail-8.14.4-9.14.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package db4-utils.x86_64 0:4.7.25-18.11.amzn1 will be obsoleted
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:4.14.94-73.73.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package kernel-tools.x86_64 0:4.14.88-72.73.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package kernel-tools.x86_64 0:4.14.94-73.73.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package krb5-libs.x86_64 0:1.15.1-19.43.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package krb5-libs.x86_64 0:1.15.1-34.44.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.53.1-16.85.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.53.1-16.86.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libdb4.x86_64 0:4.8.30-13.el7 will be obsoleting
---> Package libdb4-utils.x86_64 0:4.8.30-13.el7 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/db_stat for package: rpm-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Conflict: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 conflicts filesystem < 3
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rpm-build-libs-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: rpm-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)                                                                                                                                                 [45/1125]
           Requires: /usr/bin/db_stat
           Removing: db4-utils-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               Not found
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-utils-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               Not found
Error: Package: pam-1.1.8-12.33.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: rpm-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: libdb4 conflicts with filesystem-2.4.30-3.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Package: iproute-4.4.0-3.23.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: httpd24-2.4.37-1.83.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: python27-libs-2.7.15-1.124.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: sendmail-8.14.4-9.14.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)                                                                                                                                              [2/1125]
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: httpd24-tools-2.4.37-1.83.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-updates)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: rpm-libs-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: pam_ccreds-10-4.9.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: ruby20-libs-2.0.0.648-1.31.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: rpm-python27-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: cyrus-sasl-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: apr-util-1.5.4-6.18.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried using 'sudo yum clean all', but that didn't seem to fix the issue.